# How to write lies in quadrant $X$ symbolically?

Tags: analytic-geometry

In Trigonometry, there are a lot of questions of the form :

*Write all trigonometric ratios if $\cot x = \dfrac{12}{5}$ and x lies in **quadrant III***...

Is there some symbolic method to write that *x lies in **quadrant III***? What about $x \in$ III?

Thanks!

Comment: Here $x$ is an angle rather than a point.  So perhaps you want to write inequalities for $x$?

Comment: @hardmath Like, if $x$ lies in *quadrant III*, then I can write : $\pi \leq x \leq \dfrac{3\pi}{2}$, right?

Comment: And would $X\in$ III would have worked if $X$ was a point?

Comment: You are free to define notation for your convenience in mathematics!  Just be aware that your Readers will not recognize "$X\in$ III" as standard notation without that introduction.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Unless you plan to do this often in a document, I'd recommend just using the words rather than inventing a new term or repeating the inequalities defining the third quadrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to write "angle $x$ is in quadrant III" as $x\in [\pi,3\pi/2]$.  This notation is pretty common and would not require special definitions.

If one wants to capture the possibilities that angle $x$ "wraps around" one or more times, or goes negative to get into the third quadrant, we might write instead:

$$ x \in [\pi,3\pi/2] + 2\pi k \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb Z $$

On the other hand if one wishes to identify *points* that lie in the third quadrant, notice that these are exactly the points whose Cartesian are less than (or equal to) zero.  So we might write:

$$ (s,t) \text{ where } s,t \le 0 $$

for *points* specifically in the third quadrant.  A variation of this could be made to work for other quadrants.

Comment: Thanks! That clears all queries...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Quadrant III is the set of all points $(x,y)\in \mathrm R^2$ such that $x\le 0$ and $y\le 0.$ Can you now continue?

Comment: No, actually. I fail to understand how we can represent *angles* using this. Please elaborate...

Comment: @Rajdeep_Sindhu If $x=\cos\phi$ and $y=\sin\phi,$ then $\phi$'s being in quadrant the third is equivalent to saying $x\le 0$ and $y\le 0.$

Comment: That's a nice way to do it... Thanks!